# RobotFramework - Unable to click element using selenium library but Execute Javascript click works

Tags: python, selenium, robotframework

I am using RobotFramework to automate one application. I am using the selenium library. For the whole application, selenium keywords "Click Button" and "Click Element" throw an error stating "ElementClickInterceptedException: Message: element click intercepted: Element **** is not clickable at point (376, 289). Other element would receive the click: ..."

I am able to identify the element using ID and it is not under any iframe or shadow-root element. but still I am not able to click on the element. I also tried with adding wait commands to see if it is sync issue but it is not. I tried to click using Action class, mouse move and click etc but did not work.

I tried to take the screenshot of the element using "Capture Element Screenshot" and it captures the screenshot of an empty place however, when I try to locate element in the browser dev tool, it locate it exactly

Only working solution I found is to run "Execute Javascript" keyword to click on the element such as

```
Execute Javascript    $('#id').click();
```

Question:
Though I am able to make it work, I am curious to know what could be the issue in the application.  I am not able to share the application dom code due to restriction. Sorry for that

Answer (score 0):

This means that the element you trying to click is

1. Out of the visible screen (view port) so you need to scroll the page to make that element accessible  **or**
2. It is covered by some other element - for example you should open a drop down menu etc  **or**
3. You trying to click the element while it is still not fully rendered - in this case you need to add some delay to make the element fully rendered and be ready to accept clicks.

Selenium generally imitates human GUI actions. So, as a human user you can't click element inside drop-down without opening it. And you can't click element out of the visible screen. This is why Selenium `.click()` methods can't click such elements.
JavaScript click is more powerful tool, it can click invisible, covered etc. elements. It doesn't imitate human GUI actions.